# Android Gradle Build Plugin 4.0.0 & R8 Desugaring not working on API 19

Tags: android, java-8, android-gradle-plugin, android-r8, jdk-desugaring

I'm switching an Android application from using Proguard's desugaring to the new R8 desugaring available in Android Gradle Build Plugin 4.0.0.

I've followed the steps as detailed [in the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#j8-library-desugaring) to enable Java 8 library desugaring:

### gradle.properties

```
projectJavaVersion = 1.8
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

### app build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}
android {
    buildToolsVersion '29.0.2'
    compileSdkVersion 29
    compileOptions {
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
        sourceCompatibility projectJavaVersion
        targetCompatibility projectJavaVersion
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = projectJavaVersion
    }
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        applicationId = 'com.example.app'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            ...
            minifyEnabled true
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled true
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    coreLibraryDesugaring "com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.0.10"
    ...
}
```

You can see that we're supporting API 19 as a minimum. There are no build errors (using Gradle 6.1.1), but there are the following warnings:

```
Warning in synthesized for lambda desugaring:
  Type `j$.$r8$wrapper$java$util$function$Function$-V-WRP` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `java.util.Comparator java.time.chrono.-$$Lambda$AbstractChronology$j22w8kHhJoqCd56hhLQK1G0VLFw.thenComparing($-vivified-$.java.util.function.Function)`
Warning in synthesized for lambda desugaring:
  Type `j$.$r8$wrapper$java$util$function$ToLongFunction$-V-WRP` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `java.util.Comparator java.time.chrono.-$$Lambda$AbstractChronology$j22w8kHhJoqCd56hhLQK1G0VLFw.thenComparingLong($-vivified-$.java.util.function.ToLongFunction)`
Warning in synthesized for lambda desugaring:
  Type `j$.$r8$wrapper$java$util$function$ToDoubleFunction$-V-WRP` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `java.util.Comparator java.time.chrono.-$$Lambda$AbstractChronology$j22w8kHhJoqCd56hhLQK1G0VLFw.thenComparingDouble($-vivified-$.java.util.function.ToDoubleFunction)`
Warning in synthesized for lambda desugaring:
  Type `j$.$r8$wrapper$java$util$function$ToIntFunction$-V-WRP` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `java.util.Comparator java.time.chrono.-$$Lambda$AbstractChronology$j22w8kHhJoqCd56hhLQK1G0VLFw.thenComparingInt($-vivified-$.java.util.function.ToIntFunction)`
Warning in /Users/username/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools/desugar_jdk_libs/1.0.4/961afbdb3d41eebfb63b8c8ccdc97453b869964e/desugar_jdk_libs-1.0.4.jar:java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap$EntryIterator.class:
  Type `j$.$r8$wrapper$java$util$function$Consumer$-V-WRP` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `void java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$EntryIterator.forEachRemaining($-vivified-$.java.util.function.Consumer)`
Warning in /Users/username/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools/desugar_jdk_libs/1.0.4/961afbdb3d41eebfb63b8c8ccdc97453b869964e/desugar_jdk_libs-1.0.4.jar:java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap$CollectionView.class:
  Type `j$.$r8$wrapper$java$util$stream$Stream$-WRP` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `$-vivified-$.java.util.stream.Stream java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$CollectionView.parallelStream()`
Warning in /Users/username/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools/desugar_jdk_libs/1.0.4/961afbdb3d41eebfb63b8c8ccdc97453b869964e/desugar_jdk_libs-1.0.4.jar:java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap$CollectionView.class:
  Type `j$.$r8$wrapper$java$util$Spliterator$-WRP` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `$-vivified-$.java.util.Spliterator java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$CollectionView.spliterator()`
Warning in /Users/username/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools/desugar_jdk_libs/1.0.4/961afbdb3d41eebfb63b8c8ccdc97453b869964e/desugar_jdk_libs-1.0.4.jar:java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap$CollectionView.class:
  Type `j$.$r8$wrapper$java$util$function$Predicate$-V-WRP` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `boolean java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$CollectionView.removeIf($-vivified-$.java.util.function.Predicate)`
Warning in /Users/username/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools/desugar_jdk_libs/1.0.4/961afbdb3d41eebfb63b8c8ccdc97453b869964e/desugar_jdk_libs-1.0.4.jar:java/util/DesugarCollections$SynchronizedMap.class:
  Type `j$.$r8$wrapper$java$util$function$BiFunction$-V-WRP` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `void java.util.DesugarCollections$SynchronizedMap.replaceAll($-vivified-$.java.util.function.BiFunction)`
Warning in /Users/username/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools/desugar_jdk_libs/1.0.4/961afbdb3d41eebfb63b8c8ccdc97453b869964e/desugar_jdk_libs-1.0.4.jar:java/util/DesugarCollections$SynchronizedMap.class:
  Type `j$.$r8$wrapper$java$util$function$BiConsumer$-V-WRP` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `void java.util.DesugarCollections$SynchronizedMap.forEach($-vivified-$.java.util.function.BiConsumer)`
Warning in /Users/username/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools/desugar_jdk_libs/1.0.4/961afbdb3d41eebfb63b8c8ccdc97453b869964e/desugar_jdk_libs-1.0.4.jar:java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.class:
  Type `j$.$r8$wrapper$java$util$stream$IntStream$-WRP` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `$-vivified-$.java.util.stream.IntStream java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.ints()`
Warning in /Users/username/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools/desugar_jdk_libs/1.0.4/961afbdb3d41eebfb63b8c8ccdc97453b869964e/desugar_jdk_libs-1.0.4.jar:java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.class:
  Type `j$.$r8$wrapper$java$util$stream$LongStream$-WRP` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `$-vivified-$.java.util.stream.LongStream java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.longs()`
Warning in /Users/username/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools/desugar_jdk_libs/1.0.4/961afbdb3d41eebfb63b8c8ccdc97453b869964e/desugar_jdk_libs-1.0.4.jar:java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.class:
  Type `j$.$r8$wrapper$java$util$stream$DoubleStream$-WRP` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `$-vivified-$.java.util.stream.DoubleStream java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.doubles(long)`

Warning: Type `java.util.OptionalConversions` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `java.util.OptionalLong j$.$r8$wrapper$java$util$stream$LongStream$-WRP.findAny()`
Warning: Type `java.util.LongSummaryStatisticsConversions` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `java.util.LongSummaryStatistics j$.$r8$wrapper$java$util$stream$LongStream$-WRP.summaryStatistics()`
Warning: Type `java.util.IntSummaryStatisticsConversions` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `java.util.IntSummaryStatistics j$.$r8$wrapper$java$util$stream$IntStream$-WRP.summaryStatistics()`
Warning: Type `java.util.DoubleSummaryStatisticsConversions` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `java.util.DoubleSummaryStatistics j$.$r8$wrapper$java$util$stream$DoubleStream$-WRP.summaryStatistics()`
```

When I run the app, launching an activity with the following Optional in the code, the app crashes with

```
I/ApplicationBase: Testing Java 8
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.example.app.DEV, PID: 8265
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: j$.util.Optional
        at com.example.app.ApplicationBase.launch(ApplicationBase.java:251)
        at com.example.app.LaunchTask.doInBackground(LaunchTask.java:19)
        at com.example.app.LaunchTask.doInBackground(LaunchTask.java:6)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
```

### ApplicationBase.java

```java
import androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication
import java.util.Optional;

public class ApplicationBase extends MultiDexApplication implements LaunchTask.Launcher {
  @SuppressLint("NewApi")
  @Override
  public void launch() throws IOException {
    IOHandler ioHandler = new AndroidAppIOHandler(getApplicationContext());
    Logger.i(TAG, "Testing Java 8");
    Optional.of("xyz").ifPresent(__ -> Logger.i(TAG, "Good"));
    Logger.i(TAG, "Tested Java 8");
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

What am I missing?

---

After reading [@sgjesse's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63788372/9988519), which seemed to identify a problem with just the `launch()` method, we did some further investigation. I can confirm that `MultiDex.install()` is being called before `launch()`.

If I add an `Optional` in `AndroidAppIoHandler`, like this:

```java
public AndroidAppIOHandler(Context context) {
  this.context = context;
  final Optional<Context> context1 = Optional.of(context);
  Log.d("TESTMULTIDEX1", context1.getClass() + "  " + context1.get().getClass() + " " + context1.toString());
}
```

then I see:

```
D/TESTMULTIDEX1( 2826): class j$.util.Optional  class com.example.app.ApplicationBase Optional[com.example.app.ApplicationBase@9d006a00]
```

Which is called from the first line of `launch()`.

If I add an `Optional` to to the next line of the `launch()` method, like so:

```java
public void launch() throws IOException {
  IOHandler ioHandler = new AndroidAppIOHandler(getApplicationContext());
  final Optional<IOHandler> ioHandler1 = Optional.of(ioHandler);
  ...
```

then I see:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: j$.util.Optional
```

on the same execution, after printing the other message above!

Comment: Did you try to build it with `minifyEnabled false`?

Comment: The same thing happens with `minifyEnabled false` @dev.bmax

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Did you find an answer?

Comment: No answer yet, @DaniilPopov

Comment: First of all is the crash only on devices with API level 19? If so, it could be that the `MultiDex.install` has not been called before using desugared types. As the implementation of e.g. `java.util.Optional` (which is called `j$.util.Option` is in a separate DEX file `MultiDex.install` has to be called on devices which does not support native multi dex (which was added for API level 21). In `MultiDexApplication` the call to `MultiDex.install` is in `attachBaseContext`. If the `launch` method is invoked before `MultiDex.install` you will see the `NoClassDefFoundError`.

Comment: Thank you @sgjesse, that's nailed it. I can run the app without a crash on API 21, and moving the `Optional` to a different method (that runs after `Multidex.install`) works on API 19. I don't suppose you have any idea how I can write a unit test that fails in this case? I have several Roboelectric tests with `@Config(sdk = 19)` which all call `((ApplicationBase) ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext()).launch()` as part of the `setUp()`, but no exceptions are thrown.

Comment: Additionally if you'd like to write up your comment as an answer @sgjesse I'll mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: Good to hear that this solved your problem. Added an answer with the content. I am not that familiar with Roboelectric and desugared library. As Roboelectric does not run on a device it might be that it is not possible to directly reproduce there. Maybe you could make your own implementation of `MultiDexApplication` which keeps track of when `MultiDex.install` has been called. Then you can check in `setUp` (and other methods called early in the application lifecycle) that the desugared library is indeed loaded. Not an optimal solution. Running device tests on older devices wlll be better.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not seem to be the cause of the issue in the end - MultiDex.install is being called before launch (we tested this with the debugger).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved by upgrading to Android Gradle Build Plugin 4.2.0, where R8 desugars correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue on our legacy app, which still supports Android 4.1. After I've created a sample project and tried to reproduce the error, I've found the problem (or bug?).

Unfortunately it seems that Android devices with 4.4 or lower can't use any Java 8 class or interface which will be touched by Core Library Desugaring inside the onCreate method of the application.

It seems like a weird multi dexing issue/bug.

I tried the following:

```
class CoreApplication : MultiDexApplication() {
    override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context?) {
        //adding the new GMS causes to many Methods in APK, therefore configure Application as MultiDex
        super.attachBaseContext(base)
        MultiDex.install(this)
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        Optional.of("TEst")
    }
}
```

Which will result in your mentioned crash:

```
03-22 18:36:09.231 657-657/com.plauzeware.CoreLibraryDesugeringCrashOnAndroidKitkat E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.plauzeware.CoreLibraryDesugeringCrashOnAndroidKitkat, PID: 657
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: j$.util.Optional
        at com.plauzeware.corelibrarydesugeringcrashonandroidkitkat.CoreApplication.onCreate(Application.kt:17)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1030)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4409)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:139)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1270)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

But when I wrap the call to Optional inside a helper class

```
class Loader {
    companion object {
        fun load() {
            Optional.of("TEst")
        }
    }
}
```

and call it inside my onCreate function

```
class CoreApplication : MultiDexApplication() {
    override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context?) {
        //adding the new GMS causes to many Methods in APK, therefore configure Application as MultiDex
        super.attachBaseContext(base)
        MultiDex.install(this)
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        Loader.load()
    }
}
```

it will work. I think it's a bug and I will file a bug report and will update this answer with a Link to it.

Because the multidexing issue touches also basic interfaces like `Iterable` it's really painful to resolve those errors. Especially because we still use OrmLite and it will use `Iterable` all the time.

I've added my code for reference to my [Github](https://github.com/rzetzsche/CoreLibraryDesugeringCrashOnAndroidKitkat)

## UPDATE:

[Here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/183419297) is the link to the bug report.

Comment: Thank you, this is a really good explanation. Your time and effort are much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I was facing quite a similar issue and in my case, it turned out that it is [a bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/157681341) in Android Gradle Plugin. Long story short AGP generates a few the same wrapper classes in different DEX files that blow Dalvik/ART on old Android versions. And the problem was only on debug build because R8/ProGuard deduplicates that classes in release builds.

And there is [a workaround](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/157681341#comment22) for that issue:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://storage.googleapis.com/r8-releases/raw/master" // NOTICE 'master' here!
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools:r8:f03be11f11b8405b69876d05337e917a5519e52a'  // Must be before the Gradle Plugin for Android.
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:X.Y.Z'     // Your current AGP version.
     }
}
```

Hopefully, this will help you.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not resolve the issue, but thank you anyway!

Comment: Sorry to hear that :(

Answer (score 1):

I updated the version of my `com.android.tools.build:gradle` acording to [this table](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support?hl=pt-br#library-desugaring-versions)

Answer (score 0):

If the crash is only seen on devices with API level 19 the reason could be that the `MultiDex.install` has not been called before using desugared types.

The implementation of `java.util.Optional` (which is called `j$.util.Optional` in the desugared library) is in a separate DEX file. On devices which does not support native multi dex (which was added in API level 21) `MultiDex.install` has to be called before the desugared types can be used. In `MultiDexApplication` the call to `MultiDex.install` is in `attachBaseContext`. If the `launch` method is invoked before `MultiDex.install` you will see the `NoClassDefFoundError`.

Comment: Hey, please see the additions I made to the question - we did some investigation following your answer and unfortunately Multidex.install is being called before the launch method. Additionally we see some weirdness where Optionals work if they are used in a different object within `launch` on API 19, but not when used directly in `launch()`...